# Angular unit testing - how to test different route.snapshot.paramMap

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

In my ngOnInit function, I look at the URL and see if a parameter exists within that URL. If it does, certain actions are taken. If not, other actions are taken.

```
this.userId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

if ( (this.userId == '') || ( this.userId === null ) )
{
    ...
}else
{
    ...
}
```

I can mock the route.snapshot.paramMap in my test setup, but I obviously want to able to test for the case where the id is set in the route and the case where it is not set. How can I run both of these tests?

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ ProfileComponent ],
        providers: [ { provide: FuseTrans },
                     { provide: ActivatedRoute,     useValue : ActivatedRouteStub },
                     { provide: MatDialog,          useValue : DialogStub },
                     { provide: UserService,        useClass : UserServiceStub },
                     { provide: AuthService,        useValue : AuthServiceStub },
                     { provide: FirebaseService,    useValue : FirebaseServiceStub },
                     { provide: MatSnackBar,        useValue : SnackBarStub },
                     { provide: AngularFireStorage, useValue : AngularStorageStub } ]

    });
```

Here is the route stub. I can obviously get the test to run with any value at the "get" method. However, how do I automate the process of changing this value and rerunning the test?

```
public ActivatedRouteStub() {
    return { 'snapshot': {
                'url': [{ 'path': 1 }, { 'path': 2 }],
                'paramMap' : {
                    'get' : ()=>1,
                    'set' : ()=>{},
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```